# Django 2.0 - Urls Amigavel

Tags: python, django, url, url-amigável

Estou estudando Django 2.0.2, e estou com dificuldades em URL amigável juntamente com SlugField na classe models.py, mas não sei definir `def get_absolute_url(self):` corretamente. Eu consigo acessar direto pela URL. Falta agora definir a função na classe models para funcionar. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Abaixo o a url da minha app.

```
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from simplemooc.courses import views

app_name='courses'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path('(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.details, name='details'), 
]
```

Olhei também na documentação do Django, mas mesmo assim não entendi: [Despachante de URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/topics/http/urls/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só um pequeno ajuste no `re_path`, adicionar o `^` pra indicar início do regex e marcar a string do regex com `r`:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.details, name='details'),
```

No seu model, você pode usar o `reverse` pra retornar a URL no método `get_absolute_url()`:

**models.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models

class ModelName(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    # outros campos...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('details', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Onde `details` é o nome do seu URL.